# Hibernate OneToMany mappring error column cannot be null

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping

I have eastablished OneToMany relationship between `Company` and `product` entities show below. When I try to save `company` instance, error is thrown `column company cannot be null`. There is a constrain on `company` column that it can't be null. But why it's null? What am I missing?

Product.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="product")
public class Product {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="company")
private Company company;

public Company getCompany() {
    return company;
}

public void setCompany(Company company) {
    this.company = company;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

Company.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name="manufacturer")
public class Company {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column(name="name")
private String name;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="company")
private List<Product> products;

public List<Product> getProducts() {
    return products;
}

public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
    this.products = products;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

OnlineStore.java

```
        session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        Product shoes = new Product();
        shoes.setName("Shoes");
        Product tshirt = new Product();
        tshirt.setName("T-shirt");
        Product gloves = new Product();
        gloves.setName("Gloves");
        List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
        products.add(shoes);
        products.add(tshirt);
        products.add(gloves);
        Company addidas = new Company();
        addidas.setName("Adiddas");
        addidas.setProducts(products);
        session.save(addidas);
        tx.commit();
```

> ERROR: Column 'company' cannot be null
>   Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:59)
>       at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:207)
>       at org.hibernate.dialect.identity.GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.executeAndExtract(GetGeneratedKeysDelegate.java:57)
>       at org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:42)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2840)
>       at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3411)
>       at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:81)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:619)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:273)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:254)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:299)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:318)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:275)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:97)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSaveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:644)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.saveOrUpdate(SessionImpl.java:636)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.spi.CascadingActions$5.cascade(CascadingActions.java:219)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:391)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:316)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:424)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:356)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:319)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:155)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:104)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:445)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:281)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:182)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:113)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:192)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:38)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:177)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:32)
>       at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:73)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:675)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:667)
>       at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:662)
>       at com.onetomany.model.OnlineStore.main(OnlineStore.java:48)
>   Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Column 'company' cannot be null
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3970)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3906)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2524)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2677)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2549)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2073)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2009)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:5098)
>       at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:1994)
>       at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:204)
>       ... 41 more

Comment: There seems to be a NOT NULL constraint on the `company` column in the database. Anyway, you have to set the `company` property of each `Product` manually, e.g. `shoes.setCompany(addidas)`.

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos I think the same. But i went through a few examples about onetomany mapping and none of them have set it explicitly.